# Generic method for last record of core data base

Tags: swift, core-data

I've made a generic method which return last record from the core data base but in the return statement : `return _lastItem as! [T]` says that `Thread X: signal SIGABRT`. How can i fix this?

```
func lastRecord<T: NSManagedObject>(_ type : T.Type, sort: NSManagedObject? = nil) -> [T] {
    let _context = DataBaseController.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let _request = T.fetchRequest()
    _request.fetchLimit = 1

    do {
        let _result = try _context.fetch(_request)
        if !_result.isEmpty {
            let _lastItem = _result[0]
            return _lastItem as! [T]
        } else {
             return _result as! [T]
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error : \(error)")
        return []
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Surely `return [_lastItem] as! [T]`?

Comment: `_result` is an array. `let _lastItem = _result[0]` is a single managed object. You probably want to return `T` and not `[T]`

Comment: @MartinR Thank you for an answer!

Comment: @MartinR could u write a good way how to implement that ? Cuz all the time I am getting some errors ;/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments `_result[0]` is a single object (`T`) and cast to array (`[T]`) will crash.

Another issue is that the return type is an array, either you keep the return type

```
do {
   let _result = try _context.fetch(_request) as! [T]
    if !_result.isEmpty {
        return [_result[0]]
    } else {
         return _result
    }
} catch { ...
```

or change the return type to an optional (`T?`)

```
func lastRecord<T: NSManagedObject>(_ type : T.Type, sort: NSManagedObject? = nil) -> T? { ...
```

then the code is simply

```
do {
   let _result = try _context.fetch(_request) as! [T]
   return _result.first
} catch { ...
```

Side-note: The leading underscore characters of the local variables are quite unusual in Swift.

Comment: Whenever my database is empty the application will crash again with else statemant.

Comment: Errors thrown from here are not handler, what should i return in catch block ?

Comment: Check the balance of the braces (and the brackets). I added the actual `do` blocks.